# using ehcache blocking decorator with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I'm using ehcache with hibernate and I'd like to use the blocking or SelfPopulating cache to avoid the issues presented in http://ehcache.org/documentation/constructs-0_5.html#mozTocId722946

> An expensive operation is required, say rendering a large web page, which takes 30 seconds. The page is not considered stale until it is 5 minutes old.  The page is hit very heavily and will be hit an average of 20 times per minute each 5 minutes.

Do I have to do this programmatically as http://ehcache.org/documentation/cache_decorators.html suggests or is there a declarative (in xml) way to do so?

thanks a lot

Comment: I would like to take this opportunity to point out that 'ehcache' is a palindrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in `ehcache.xml` since you must register the class with the `CacheManager` before the cache config is read.

So you must use the code mentioned in the docs and you must run this code before you do anything with Hibernate. A simple way to do this is to use the `hibernate.cache.provider_class` property which tells Hibernate a factory for the cache. Have a look at the [source of an implementation](http://ehcache.org/xref/net/sf/ehcache/hibernate/SingletonEhCacheProvider.html) which should give you an idea what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight. I'm already using SingletonEhCacheProvider and the implementation is final (I cannot extend it). Should I duplicate the code or would a custom servlet filter do the job?