# Does Ehcache 2.1 support the transactional cache concurrency strategy in Hibernate 3.3.2GA?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, transactions, ehcache

Does [Ehcache 2.1](http://dsoguy.blogspot.com/2010/04/ehcache-21-beta-lots-of-stuff-still.html) now support the [transactional cache concurrency strategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache-transactional) in Hibernate 3.3.2GA?  That is, does Hibernate, when configured to use Ehcache 2.1 as its cache provider, allow the `<cache usage="transactional"/>` element in a mapping file or the Hibernate entity class annotation `@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Ehcache [Home Page](http://ehcache.org/) page, Ehcache 2.1+ does now support all Hibernate strategies:

> #### 17 May 2010: Ehcache 2.1.0 and new ehcache-nonstopcache and
>
> ehcache-unlockedreadsview released
>
> Ehcache 2.1.0 rounds out Ehcache 2.0.
>   **JTA support has been added for
>   standalone ehcache. JTA for Hibernate
>   has been added which now means Ehcache
>   supports all Hibernate strategies**.
>   ehcache-nonstopcache adds a new API
>   with support for timeouts on Cache
>   Operations and configurable actions on
>   disconnection from a cluster.
>   ehcache-unlockedreadsview adds support
>   for a coherent cache to expose an
>   unlocked view at the same time, for
>   rapid response.

#### See also

- [Ehcache 2.1 Beta - Lots of Stuff, Still Backward Compatible](http://dsoguy.blogspot.com/2010/04/ehcache-21-beta-lots-of-stuff-still.html)